# require and *modules* are deprecated in common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

[Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_provid.htm#require) says that ***require*** and ****modules**** are deprecated.

But I still see we use ***require*** all the time. What should we use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They were deprecated long ago. The standard was published in 1994. What were the consequences? **None**, since no new standard has been published and no new standard is being worked on.

**So, if your Common Lisp implementations provide a useful definition and implementation of PROVIDE, REQUIRE and *MODULES*, then use it.**

There are other tools that care about loading and creating libraries and applications (usually called 'Systems'). Often these have some kind of interface, so that (REQUIRE 'SOME-SYSTEM) loads that system and so that after loading that system it has been 'provided'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One little question. Isn't it strange that the spec just deprecated something without providing substitutes?

Comment: @yehnan, sometimes you realize that the functionality described is just not very useful or lacks detail, but there is no will or capability to specify a better one. The standard committee discussed several areas of extensions, but failed, ran out of steam, ran out of money, ran out of interested parties..,

Comment: Is there some documentation as to what they thought should have replaced require? Did they want to eventually go for an ASDF style system?

Comment: @omouse: 'modules' were to go without replacement, AFAIK. See: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss296_w.htm . It was also proposed to add a SYSTEM facility, for example by Kent Pitman: http://www.nhplace.com/kent/CL/Issues/defsystem.html

Answer (score 5):

[ASDF](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/) seems to be a pretty popular and modern way for loading systems.

to load foo:

> (asdf:load-system :foo)

and under ABCL, Clozure CL, CMUCL, ECL and SBCL, it hooks into cl:require. So cl:require seems fine.